# Simulate HTTP_IV_USER in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

Our customer uses an SSO module so that sets the current user ID into `HTTP_IV_USER` server variable. I have inherited code from an application that was *patched* to allow automatic login and I have done many modifications to it in the past year, making it work fine for customers with a standard setup.

Now I am asked to deploy the application at customer site with SSO plugin, so I need to test whether the patch still works. Unfortunately, the customer won't allow us to access their systems for testing (they will install our package to QA and do their QA independently from us). Neither they will provide us details on the SSO (e.g. SiteMinder version xxxx) because "you [us] have already the code".

I just need to perform a few login tests with my development version to assure that it will work in their environment, nothing more.

I am simply asking how can I emulate `Request.ServerVariables.GetValues("HTTP_IV_USER")[0]`? How does IIS (which is going to be upgraded to 7.5 as part of the software upgrade process) set that variable?

I have tried to do my homework and found that `HTTP_IV_USER` is not a request header (that could be set using Firebug or other tricks) but an environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering for posterity.

The trick is that `HTTP_IV_USER` is really an HTTP header, exactly like `Request.Headers["IV_USER"]`

Being able to emulate `IV_USER` header opens the gate to emulating `HTTP_IV_USER`.

This is because [IIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) translates all HTTP headers to `HTTP_` prefixed server variables